# Div-fired galleries in Fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox two and instead of using the `<a>` tags to fire Fancybox I'm using `div` tags and within my Javascript I'm using this code:

```
$('#portfolio>#project').click(function(){
    $background_image = $(this).css("background-image");
    $background_image = $background_image.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
    $.fancybox({
        href: $background_image
    });
});
```

However, by following the Fancybox documentation to create a gallery (by adding `rel="gallery1"` to your images, or in my case, `div`s), there is no slideshow and you can't navigate from one image to the other when the Fancybox is fired and an image appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody really had the answer to my question I decided to sit back and take a long and hard look at my code; I came to the decision that I needed to create a plugin for this to work.

When I was developing my portfolio (http://mrconnor.co.uk) I developed it so that instead of Fancybox being fire from `<a>` tags I'd fire it from `<div>` tags: I did this so that my code could be cleaner, plus it would be easier for me to good back and edit and style.

However, I came across the problem (which is why I posted) that making a gallery or a slideshow from this cannot work the normal way by adding `rel="gallery1"` to all items that I want in my gallery, so I created a jQuery plugin.

**Test it here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/cranavvo/u3U23/

```
$.fn.fancyGallery = function($gallery_name){
    $(this).each(function(){
        $background_image = $(this).css("background-image");
        $background_image = $background_image.replace('url(','').replace(')','');

        $(this).attr({
            "data-fancybox-group": $gallery_name,
            "data-fancybox-href": $background_image
        });     
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always bind any html element to fancybox other than the `<a>` tag (and create a gallery without the `rel` attribute), using fancybox's special `data-fancybox-*` attributes like :

```
<div data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-fancybox-href="#inline1" class="fancybox">open first fancybox item</div>
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SMNe9/1/)</kbd>

BTW, if binding fancybox to more than one element, use *classes* instead of IDs

**NOTE**: if you use the method `.click()` to fire fancybox, the gallery should be manually passed to fancybox within the script. You still can bind a `click` to the element (to populate the content of the target element) before binding fancybox to it like :

```
$(".fancybox").click(function(){
    // populate the target inline element here
}).fancybox();
```