# Open fancybox when click on a div

Tags: jquery, html, click, fancybox

I often use `<a>` tag with `href` in order to call fancybox. Now, I'm thinking about opening fancybox (ver1) with a `div` click.

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Div-fired galleries in Fancybox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341979/div-fired-galleries-in-fancybox)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just use `data-fancybox-*` attributes in your `div`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21342394/1055987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to bind any element other than the `<a>` tag to fancybox (v2.x) using (HTML5) `data-fanncybox-*` attributes.

Unfortunately, `data-fanncybox-*` attributes **are not** an option for *fancybox v1.3.x*, however you still can use standard `data-*` attributes in your `<div>` and **[extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)** fancybox (v1.3.x) functionality within the `onStart` callback.

So assuming that you want to call fancybox from a `div` like :

```
<div class="fancybox" data-href="image.jpg">This DIV should open fancybox</div>
```

**Notice** the `data-href` attribute that will tell fancybox where it should get the content from (similar to `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag)

Then, you can use this script :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type: "image",
    onStart: function (el, index) {
        var thisElement = $(el[index]);
        $.extend(this, {
            href: thisElement.data("href")
        });
    }
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XBWFr/)</kbd>

---

On the other hand, building fancybox (v1.3.x) galleries with elements other than `<a>` **is not** as easy as just adding a `rel` attribute to the `<div>` element because it will trigger a js error.

As a workaround, you are pushed to build the gallery manually within the script. You could do that using the `.each()` method like :

```
var gallery = [];
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").each(function (i) {
        gallery[i] = {
            href: $(this).data("href"),
            title : "image "+ (i+1)
        };
        $(this).on("click", function () {
            $.fancybox(gallery, {
                // API v1.3.x options here
                type: "image",
                index: i, // IMPORTANT to open from clicked div
                cyclic: true
            }); // fancybox
            return false;
        }); // on
    }); // each
}); // ready
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rMe4x/1/)</kbd>

**NOTES**:

- this solutions is for fancybox v1.3.x
- `.on()` requires jQuery 1.7+